# How to use internal packages with go modules?

Tags: go, shared, go-modules

I am using go modules in my project. I have shared code in the internal folder.

```
.
├── README.md
├── internal
│   └── shared
│       ├── request.go
│       └── request_test.go
└── web
    ├── README.md
    └── go
        └── src
            └── webservice
                ├── go.mod
                ├── go.sum
                └── main.go
```

I am not able to access the internal/shared from webservice while using go modules. I get the following error:

```
package internal/shared is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/internal/shared)
```

While importing from webservice in main.go:

```
import "internal/shared"
```

Note: I am trying to share internal/shared with another mod that is not listed above.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: `internal` isn't part of the `webservice` module. Either move `internal` into the correct location, or make the entire project a single module. The code layout is quite unusual, is there a reason it's structured in this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up fixing by adding a go.mod to the internal/shared and editing the go.mod in webservice with the following:

```
module webservice

go 1.14

replace example.com/shared => ../../../../internal/shared/

require (
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.7.4
    github.com/spf13/viper v1.6.3
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.5.1
    example.com/shared v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
)
```

example.com/shared v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000 was generated by `"go mod init webservice"`

Answer (score 9):

Your `go.mod` inside `web/go/src/webservice` indicates that this package is located in a different module than your `internal/shared` package.
It should work when you move your `go.mod` and `go.sum` at the root of the whole project. Then the `web/go/src/webservice` and `internal/shared` packages will be inside one `go module`.

This worked for me:

```
    .
    ├── go.mod
    ├── go.sum
    ├── internal
    │   └── shared
    │       └── request.go
    │  
    └── web
        └── go
            └── src
                └── webservice
                    └── main.go
```

And you should include the whole `go-module` path when importing the `internal/shared` package in your `main.go`.

So, inside your `main.go` the import should look like `import "$your-go-module/internal/shared"`

More info on internal packages [here](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#internalpackages)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the code was compiling fine, but the GoLand IDE was unable to recognise the imports. The issue was exactly as described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/9gzffo/anyone_using_go_modules_directory_outside_of/).

> I'm using go modules and a directory outside of the GOPATH. External dependencies are recognized just fine, packages inside my projects "cannot be found" by GoLand.
>
> The fix is to tick the checkbox for *Enable Go Modules (vgo) integration* under Settings/Preference -> Go -> Go Modules (vgo). 
>  
>  Here is the screenshot for the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share libraries in Monorepo, we use `go mod edit -require` and `go mod edit -replace` to place each of these dependencies in the go.mod files for each of the services that require the shared packages.

Given

```
monorepo/
        |_service-1
                |_api/
                |_main.go
                |_go.mod
                |_go.sum
        |_service-2
                |_api/
                |_main.go
                |_go.mod
                |_go.sum
        |_shared_package_1
                |_helpers.go
                |_go.mod
                |_go.sum
        |_shared_package_2
                |common.go
                |_go.mod
                |_go.sum
```

```
cd service-1
go mod edit -require=passage.id/shared_package_1@v0.0.0
go mod edit -replace=passage.id/shared_package_1@v0.0.0=../shared_package_1
go mod edit -require=passage.id/shared_package_2@v0.0.0
go mod edit -replace=passage.id/shared_package_21@v0.0.0=../shared_package_1
```

After doing this, we are able to use any of the functions declared in any of these shared packages inside of the service-1 microservice the same way we would an external package.

Refer to this [doc](https://passage.id/post/shared-go-packages-in-a-monorepo)